# Programatically upload html files to a web server with nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, discord.js

I have a discord js bot with tickets system (A system where users can create private channel and ask staff for help). When a channel is deleted, my bot saves all messages and creates html file with messages that were in that channel. I want to upload that file to a web server so users can review it without having to download it, but I am unsure how to do it. The below variable `attachment` holds the html file/string to be uploaded.

```
const attachment = await discordTranscripts.createTranscript(channel, {
      limit: -1, // Max amount of messages to fetch.
      returnType: 'attachment', // Valid options: 'buffer' | 'string' | 'attachment' Default: 'attachment'
      fileName: fileName, // Only valid with returnBuffer false. Name of attachment. 
      minify: true // Minify the result? Uses html-minifier
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite **opinion-based** question. There are a lot of ways to do it.

**SSH**

You can use [Node SSH](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ssh) to log into your server via `SSH` and upload the file.

**Rest API**

Host a simple and secure **Rest API** in the server to write the **HTML file** and call it from your main application.

**AWS S3**

If you are using **AWS**, Create an **S3 Bucket**, make it **publicly readable** and enable **static web hosting**. Now you can put your **HTML files** to your **S3 Bucket** using `AWS-SDK` and access them via **S3 Bucket Url**.

> If you are using some other cloud platform like Azure / GCP, Checkout their own storage service.